# How to center an ngx-bootstrap modal

Tags: css, angular, centering, ngx-bootstrap, ngx-bootstrap-modal

Trying to center this [ngx-boostrap modal](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals#service-template) using CSS like this but it's not working:

```
.modal.fade.in{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

But in the dev tool, I'm able to add CSS like this:

```
.modal.dialog{
  top: 50%
}
```

So at least it is centered vertically, but this is in the dev tool, and there is no `.modal.dialog`class in the [html template](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals#service-template)

Is there a way to center properly the ngx-bootstrap modal ?

I want to create a generic modal component to use it anywhere, by providing an input message and adding a yes/no dialog and output the user choice (using EventEmitter)

I've found an example in the following [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/NJRvUMZN2kHZruFgeOjQ?p=preview), but not able to reproduce it in a separate custom component.

The plunker example comes from this website: https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/issues/2334

**Update:**

After @Wira Xie answer, when I use the [Static modal](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals#static) and this CSS:

```
.modal-sm
{
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width:30em;
  height:18em;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
}
```

The modal shows centered, but only the `Esc key` can hide it, so when I click outside the modal, it's still visible.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Why not to use bootstrap `modal-dialog-centered` class:

```
this.modalRef2 = this.modalService.show(ModalContentComponent,
     {
       class: 'modal-dialog-centered', initialState 
     }
);
```

Comment: HDJEMAI mrapi I added this class and it reflected in html with modal-dialog but no effect.

Comment: It worked for me, maybe your version of bootstrap is outdated?
`, initialiState`shouldn't be there however.

Comment: Not working in this example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-bootstrap-fxafa1?file=app/app.component.ts using bootstrap 4.3.1, Any idea why ?

Comment: Any Stackblitz that can demo this in Bootstarp 3 or 4, that I can accept this answer ?

Comment: @mrapi: can you provide a Stackblitz demo link for this.

Comment: @mrapi: I was able to test this with Bootstrap 4 in a project, so it works, I accepted the solution. it will be more interesting if you can add a Stackblitz example to this answer, that it can help more people.

Comment: I don't use Stackblitz,if you are have a working link post it here

Answer (score 13):

in the .ts file you have a code like this (to open modal popup)...

```
private showModal(template: TemplateRef<any>): BsModalRef {
    return this.modalService.show(
      template,
      { class: 'modal-lg modal-dialog-centered',
        ignoreBackdropClick: true, 
        keyboard: false
      });
}
```

You can see that I've added modal-dialog-centered to the class. after doing this you can also modify the modal-dialog-centered class in your css.

Comment: perfect for me!

Answer (score 9):

Try adding this attribute to your CSS: `vertical-align: middle` to your `.modal.dialog` class

[Plunker for modal](https://plnkr.co/edit/NJRvUMZN2kHZruFgeOjQ?p=preview)

```
.modal.fade {
    display: flex !important;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.modal-dialog {
    vertical-align:middle;
    height:18em;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
}
```

Comment: `class: 'modal-dialog-centered'` why not just add this as suggested in other answer, is your method to be used in certain situations?

Answer (score 5):

You need to use the [bootstrap class](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/modal/#vertically-centered).

> Add `.modal-dialog-centered` to `.modal-dialog` to vertically center the modal.

```
import { Component, OnInit, TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';
import { BsModalService } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';
import { BsModalRef } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal/bs-modal-ref.service';

@Component({
...
})
export class ModalComponent {
  modalRef: BsModalRef;

  // Here we add another class to our (.modal.dialog)
  // and we need to pass this config when open our modal
  config = {
    class: 'modal-dialog-centered'
  }

  constructor(private modalService: BsModalService) { }

  openModal(template: TemplateRef<any>) {
    // pass the config as second param
    this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(template, this.config);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass the `modal-dialog-centered` bootstrap class for the `BsModalService.show()` function like this:

```
 const initialState = {
      organization: organization,
 };

 this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(AdminOrganizationCreateComponent, {
      class: 'modal-dialog-centered', initialState 
 });
```

Note: if you need to pass initial data you can pass it using the `initalState` object.

Comment: What is new in this answer ? it's just a copy-paste of the accepted one !

Answer (score 1):

A bit late, but for reference.

The reason the styling of the dialog in the component is not working, is because component styling is isolated and restricted to elements within the component. The dialog created through the bsmodalservice is outside of this component. (directly under `<body>`).

So, while your styling is encapsulated in the component and some random identifier, the dialog itself is not. The final css (like `mycomponent[_ngcontent_bla_323] .modal`) does not apply to the div.modal that is added by the service.

Possible solutions are:

- Move your css for this dialog to some global (s)css file instead of the (s)css for the component
- Instead of using bsModalService with a template, use the bsmodal directive with a div within your component. That way the component local (s)css will apply.

Answer (score 0):

I have added `mat-step` inside the modal and because of that it didn't align centered for `modal-dialog-centered` bootstrap class ether. But `modal-lg` class worked for me. Sample code is very similar to the accepted answer. Only change the bootstrap class which is passed to the modal.

```
this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(AddDevelopersGroupComponent,{
      class: 'modal-lg',
      initialState,
});
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a snippet from my personal project using ngx-bootstrap too.

```css
.modal-sm
{
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width:30em;
    height:18em;
    margin-top: -9em; 
    margin-left: -15em; 
    background-color: #001b00; 
    /*position:fixed;*/
}
```

```html
<!--typecript files-->
<script>
//here is the typesciprt file
export class AppComponent 
{ 
    //for default ngx-bootstrap modal
    public modalRef: BsModalRef;
    constructor(private modalService: BsModalService) {}

    public openModal(template: TemplateRef<any>) {
      this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(template);
    }
}
</script>
<!--end of ts file-->

<!--Modal-->
<div class="container">
    <div bsModal #smModal="bs-modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h4 class="modal-title pull-left">Small modal</h4>
              <button type="button" class="close pull-right" aria-label="Close" (click)="smModal.hide()">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
<!--enf of modal-->
```

Comment: There is an error when I click on: Run code snippet

Comment: Maybe because jsfiddle doesn't support angular typescript yet. I Simply just put a `.modal-sm` to my css. `.modal-sm` can be found at `<div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">`

Comment: you can try to provide Plunker, I'll test that and see

Comment: I'm not really familiar code with plunker, maybe you can provide your modal html.

Comment: This is a bad quality example, that a) isn't working and b) doesn't show the correct source code on how to infer an anywhere near correct answer!

Answer (score -1):

According to the [documentation](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/api) you can center the modal vertically via setting centered property to true (as it is false by default)

```
const modalRef = this.modalService.open(ConfirmationDialogComponent, {
      size: dialogSize,
      centered: true 
    });
```

Comment: you are referencing to the other (similar) library NG-bootstrap that is NOT the asked library NGX-bootstrap